# Converting unix time to DateTime

Tags: vb.net, unix, datetime

I would like to convert a Unix time stamp to a VB.NET DateTime.

I have tried

```
Public Function UnixToDateTime(ByVal strUnixTime As String) As DateTime

    Dim nTimestamp As Double = strUnixTime
    Dim nDateTime As System.DateTime = New System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    nDateTime.AddSeconds(nTimestamp)

    Return nDateTime

End Function
```

But when I feed it

```
strUnixTime = "1401093810"
```

I get the return value

```
nDateTime = #1/1/1970#
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line of code

```
nDateTime.AddSeconds(nTimestamp)
```

does *not* modify `nDateTime`. It's like writing `a + 3` on a line by it's own -- `a` won't be modified.

It does, however, *return a new DateTime object* that contains the incremented value. So, what you actually wanted to write is:

```
nDateTime = nDateTime.AddSeconds(nTimestamp)
```

PS: It appears that your code does not use `Option Strict On`. It is strongly recommended that you activate `Option Strict` and use explicit instead of implicit conversions.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get the date, but do you perhaps also know how I can get a DateTime? Currently, the time is missing: nDateTime = #4/5/2006#

Comment: It's not missing! A DateTime/Date variable *always* contains a time component. It's just that *the debugger* might not show the time component if it's `00:00`.

Comment: addseconds return date object not datetime objects. I wonder if there is any difference

Comment: @user4951: There isn't. `Date` is VB's synonym for `DateTime`.